# C~ LINQ search functionality on multiple table

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, asp.net-web-api

I am trying to build a search functionality and I am looking for building a Expression tree.

Sorry to be frank I not sure which approach to take..

I have three table to search and based on 3 search field.

**Table 1:**

[image]

**Table 2:**

[image]

**Table 3:**

[image]

Search Field I have are:

1. TCode [Table1]
2. Band [Table2]
3. RTCode [Table3]

**OutPut List:**

TCode , Band , T1Id.

```
Class Response{
public string TCode {get;set}
public string RTCode {get;set}
public int Band {get;set}
}
```

I tried to get `IQuerable<Table1>` and started to build search condition like

```
queryObj = IQuerable<Table1>
 If(TCode not empty)
{
      queryObj = queryObj.Where(x=>x.TCode== input.TCode));
 }
If(Band not Empty)
{
   queryObj = queryObj.Include(x=>x.table2.Where(x=>x.Brand==input.Brand))
}

if(rTcode Not empty)
{
  queryObj = queryObj.Include(x=>x.table3.Where(x=>x.RTCode==input.RTCode)
}
```

Then I want to select TCode , Band , T1Id Column.

```
var queryObj.SelectMany(x=>x.table2).Select(y=> new Response(){
T1Id = y.T1Id,
Band= y.Band,
TCode = y.Table1.TCode
}).ToList()
```

I am getting The property expression Not valid error on converting to ToList.

> The property expression 'x => {from Table2 y in
>   [_1].Table2 where ([y].Band == __inputObj_Band_0) select
>   [y]}' is not valid.  The expression should represent a property
>   access: 't => t.MyProperty'.

I am sure the above statement is not correct.

So can anyone advise me how to approach this search functionally, so that it can be extended at any point on different field or adding more table as well.

Comment: Do you have actual EF code to show us? Could you post the actual query you tried?

Comment: updated the code..

Comment: Your last code excerpt can't compile. Please post some code ready to use.

Anyway, if you are using EF, do you have foreign keys ? if yes, then the framework will let you navigate through the entities to get the elements you want - the expression tree will be compiled by the JIT.

Comment: So table1 has a table2 object?

Comment: That EF Object Graph.. since T1Id is Foreign key in Table2 & even in Table 3.

Comment: In your final code block, do you mean to assign to a variable, for example `var result = queryObj.SelectMany(x=>x.table2)...`?

Comment: @KevinC Funny how one can overlook something so simple sometimes.

Comment: Yes.. currently most of my Response class gets populated from Table 2.

Comment: *not empty*, *not **E**mpty* and ***N**ot **E**mpty*. I just died from consistency OCD!